# HTTPS request using DES-CBC-SHA and latest version of Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, pyopenssl, urllib3

I'm trying to set up `https` connection from `Python` on `Windows` using `Requests` to Cisco ASA firewall which does not have `AES/3DES` license installed. The goal is to download `pcap` capture file from URL pattern `https://10.0.0.1/capture/TEST_CAPTURE/pcap` but it does not really matter for the question further and we'll consider URL to be `https://10.0.0.1`.

With default `Requests` setup a connection attempt  fails for both `Python 2` and `Python 3`:

```
requests.get('https://10.0.0.1', verify = False, auth = ('username','password'))
...
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:600)
```

This could be due to lack of cipher overlap between the server and the client. `CURL` with `-v` option was used to determine what cipher is used by the server:

```
CURL -u username -v -l -k https://10.0.0.1
...
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
SSL connection using DES-CBC-SHA
...
```

The server is using `DES-CBC-SHA` cipher and I can't change that. So this cipher was added to a list of default ciphers for `urllib3`:

```
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += ':DES-CBC-SHA'
```

After that for `Python 3` version `3.4.3` connection succeeded but for `Python 2` version `2.7.12` it still failed. And I do need to use `Python 2`. I tried to install security dependencies:

```
pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
```

And to add `DES-CBC-SHA` cipher to `pyopenssl` list of default ciphers:

```
requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.DEFAULT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST += ':DES-CBC-SHA'
```

But connecton from `Python 2.7.12` still failed with the same error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')],)",)
```

It was noticed that `Python 3.4.3` for which the connection succeeds uses an older version of `openssl` than `Python 2.7.12` for which the connection fails:

```
Python 3.4.3
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
'OpenSSL 1.0.1l 15 Jan 2015'

Python 2.7.12
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
'OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016'
```

And after replacing `Python 2.7.12` with `Python 2.7.9` which has `'OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014'`, the connection succeeded.

Is it possible to establish `https` connection using `DES-CBC-SHA` cipher with the latest version of `Python`?